# Initialize a Map containing arrays in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to make a `Map` where each member contains an array of strings. But how do I initialize and type it (in a single statement)?

(naively) I tried this:

```
  private _gridOptions:Map<string, Array<string>> = {"1": ["test"]};
```

and I get:

```
Module build failed: Error: /Users/*****/Work/dashboard/src/app/core/pg.service.ts (8,5): Type '{ "1": string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, string[]>'.
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Per [Mozilla's Map documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Relation_with_Array_objects), you can initialize as follows:

```
private _gridOptions:Map<string, Array<string>> = 
    new Map([
        ["1", ["test"]],
        ["2", ["test2"]]
    ]);
```

Comment: It should be noted that information on how to explicitly type this is not on the page you have linked to.

Answer (score 7):

```
variableName: Map<string, string[]> = new Map();
```

**To push elements into Map:**

```
variableName.set("a", ["b", "c"]);
```

**To get/retrieve elements from map:**

```
variableName.get(key);// "a" in above case
```

Or **directly use**

```
variableName: Map<string, string[]> = new Map([['a', ['b', 'c']]]);
```